# Pandas - Rolling average for a group across multiple columns; large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| ID1 | ID2 | Box1_weight | Box2_weight | Average Prev Weight ID1 |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
|  19 | 677 |      3      |      2      |            -            |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| 677 |  19 |      1      |      0      |            2            |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
|  19 | 677 |      3      |      1      |      (0 + 3 )/2=1.5     |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
|  19 | 677 |      7      |      0      |       (3+0+3)/3=2       |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| 677 |  19 |      1      |      3      |      (0+1+1)/3=0.6      |
```

I want to work out the moving average of weight the past 3 boxes, based on ID. I want to do this for all IDs in ID1.

I have put the column I want to calculate, along with the calculations is in the table above, labelled "Average Prev Weight ID1"

---

I can get a a rolling average for each individual column using the following:

```
df_copy.groupby('ID1')['Box1_weight'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(period_length, min_periods=1).mean())
```

However, this does not take into account that the item may also have been packed in the column labelled "Box2_weight"

How can I get a rolling average that is per ID, across the two columns?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt

stack the 2 ids and 2 weights columns to create dataframe with 1 ids and 1 weight column. Calculate the running average and assign back the running average for ID1 back to the dataframe

I have used your code of calculating rolling average but I arranged data to df2 before doing ti

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
    "ID1": [19,677,19,19,677],
    "ID2": [677, 19, 677,677, 19],
    "Box1_weight": [3,1,3,7,1],
    "Box2_weight": [2,0,1,0,3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
display(df)

period_length=3
ids = df[["ID1", "ID2"]].stack().values
weights = df[["Box1_weight", "Box2_weight"]].stack().values

df2=pd.DataFrame(dict(ids=ids, weights=weights))

rolling_avg = df2.groupby("ids")["weights"] \
    .apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(period_length, min_periods=1)
    .mean()).values.reshape(-1,2)

df["rolling_avg"] = rolling_avg[:,0]


display(df)
```

**Result**

```
ID1 ID2 Box1_weight Box2_weight
0   19  677 3   2
1   677 19  1   0
2   19  677 3   1
3   19  677 7   0
4   677 19  1   3


ID1 ID2 Box1_weight Box2_weight rolling_avg
0   19  677 3   2   NaN
1   677 19  1   0   2.000000
2   19  677 3   1   1.500000
3   19  677 7   0   2.000000
4   677 19  1   3   0.666667
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to get the result. I will study this solution in some detail and test with my broader data.

Comment: dict is used to initialize new dataframe it has only two keys which each stores numpy array. You can replace that line with ```df2=pd.DataFrame()

df2["ids"] = ids
df2["weights"] = weights```
but I don't think it is better in anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a good solution.  I figured out the issue - it was missing values. I will now try and create a rolling average column for the boxes in ID2. Would I need to reprocess the arrays as above?

Comment: no, the average is already calculated in ```rolling_avg[:,1]``` just assign it to another column

Comment: Perfect - I will study your solution in detail as I am new to pandas and this is super helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want. I had trouble understanding your requirements. But here's a go:

```
ids = ['ID1', 'ID2']
ind = np.argsort(df[ids].to_numpy(), 1)

make_sort = lambda s, ind: np.take_along_axis(s, ind, axis=1)

f = make_sort(df[ids].to_numpy(), ind)
s = make_sort(df[['Box1_weight', 'Box2_weight']].to_numpy(), ind)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([f,s], 1), columns=df.columns)

res1 = df2.groupby('ID1').Box1_weight.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().shift()
res2 = df2.groupby('ID2').Box2_weight.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().shift()

means = pd.concat([res1,res2], 1).rename(columns={'Box1_weight': 'w1', 'Box2_weight': 'w2'})
x = df.set_index([df.ID1.values, df.index])

final = x[ids].merge(means, left_index=True, right_index=True)[['w1','w2']].sum(1).sort_index(level=1)

df['final_weight'] = final.tolist()
```

---

```
   ID1  ID2  Box1_weight  Box2_weight  final_weight
0   19  677            3            2      0.000000
1  677   19            1            0      2.000000
2   19  677            3            1      1.500000
3   19  677            7            0      2.000000
4  677   19            1            3      0.666667
```