# Smoothed Average over rows and columns with pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a function that averages over both row and column. For example:

```
**State**      **1943 1944 1945  1946  1947 (1947_AVG) 1948   (1948_AVG)**

Alaska          1      2     3     4    5      2         6        3

CA               234   234   234  6677 34
```

I want a code that will give me an average for 1947 using 1943, 1944, and 1945. Something that gives me 1948 using 1944, 1945, 1946, ect, ect.

I currently have:

```
d3['pandas_SMA_Year'] = d3.iloc[:,1].rolling(window=3).mean()
```

But this is simply working over the rows, not the columns, and it doesn't take into account the fact that I'm looking 2 years back. Please and thank you for any guidance!

Comment: What is the expected output with the given data ?

Comment: It should be something like: 1947 (SMA_1947) 1948 (SMA_1948) 1949 (SMA_1949) so that there is "smoothed average" for every year/state... Perhaps it would help to switch the rows and columns?

Comment: I meant, can you provide the expected output, dataframe structure and the corresponding values.

Comment: It is similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049185/pandas-rolling-average-for-a-group-across-multiple-columns-large-dataframe, but instead of rolling over two columns, it needs to roll over 3 each time.

Comment: I've amended the post to be more clear @DOOM